# If module.exports creates a new class, is it newly created if called with require? Or does it only work with one? in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, require, module.exports

I'm worried about the memory increase.

If I use require as below, does the class create memory every time?

```
------------ a.js -------------`
class a {
 constructor(){
   }
}

module.exports = new a();
---------------
```

```
const IsMemoryIncrease = require('a');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this

```
// b.js
const IsMemoryIncrease1 = require('./a');
const IsMemoryIncrease2 = require('./a');

console.log(IsMemoryIncrease1);
console.log(IsMemoryIncrease2);
console.log(IsMemoryIncrease2 == require('./a'));
```

Comment: I got "true" of the return value.
If so, does it mean that it works like a singleton with the same guy every time it is called?
So no worries about increasing memory?

Thanks. deserve to be blessed.

Answer (score 1):

Once a module is loaded, it is cached by the system.  Subsequent attempts to load that module again just return the exact same `module.exports` that was previously created.  The module initialization code is not run again.

So, in your case, every module that loads `a.js` will get the exact same instance of the `a` class.  There will only be one instance.

Comment: is there an option to avoid this?

Comment: @karthiksuryadevara - This is the way modules work.  Instead of exporting a singleton object, you can export a function that returns a new object every time it is called so that that whoever is loading the module can call that function to get a new object.